# How can I send HTML tag string in REST API by using Swift Alamofire?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3, swift4

I need to send HTML string to server.
I am using Swift alamofire and when I try to call Rest api then getting ccs code response from server.
same body format used in PostMan and it's working good.

My request body parameters:

```
{body = "<br/><br/>Hi Bhavdip,<br/><br/>Please find the One-Time Password (OTP) as requested through application.<br/>OTP- 123456 <br/><br/>Kindly, enter this OTP in your mobile application to authenticate your account and change phone number.<br/><br/>Kind regard,<br/>VeriDoc Global Team.";subject = "VeriDoc Global OTP for Account Verification";toaddress = "bambhroliya.bhavdip@example.com"; toname = "Bhavdip Patel";}
```

Response:

> invalid json format. getting css code.
>   Param Value is

```
"<br/><br/>Hi Bhavdip,<br/><br/>Please find the One-Time Password (OTP) as requested through application.<br/>OTP- 123456 <br/><br/>Kindly, enter this OTP in your mobile application to authenticate your account and change phone number.<br/><br/>Kind regard,<br/>VeriDoc Global Team."
```

Comment: "My request body parameters:" Could you show some code on how did you get that? Also, why does it seems like being a `NSDictionary` and not a Swift Dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

```swift
let params = [body = "<br/><br/>Hi Bhavdip,<br/><br/>Please find the One-Time Password (OTP) as requested through application.<br/>OTP- 798580 <br/><br/>Kindly, enter this OTP in your mobile application to authenticate your account and change phone number.<br/><br/>Kind regard,<br/>VeriDoc Global Team.",subject = "VeriDoc Global OTP for Account Verification",toaddress = "bambhroliya.bhavdip@tristonsoft.com", toname = "Bhavdip Patel"] as! [String:Any]
```

use this as your params